# Dynamic welcome <user> of navbar in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dynamic

I have a doubt regarding dynamically rendering the logged in user's name in the NavBar in react.

So my app is structured in the following way

```
<App>
<Header/>
<Router>
....
<Router/>
<Footer/>
<App/>
```

Now inside the header component, I need to display "Welcome <user>" whenever the user is logged in. Here are some solutions that I thought of,but Not sure if I'm missing out on anything.

1. To send it as a prop to the header. But it can only be dynamic if I do a setState in the App component and re render the entire app component (Which I want to avoid)
2. To store it in redux, so header can dynamically get the updated. But since I am using JWT, and the user needs to stay logged in, If the user refreshes the page, store content will be wiped out.
3. I can store the username in localstorage as well, but the entire app would still need to be re rendered in order to display the change

-) I think it can be accomplished in Angular by BehaviorSubject, but in this scenario, I'm clueless.

Is there any solution or method that I am missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first if you want to keep your user logged in then you have to store the `JWT` somewhere. Here by 'somewhere' I mean, so that you can access it on next reload.

In my maximum project I store my `JWT` in local-storage. It works something like this

- When user logs in I store the `JWT` in local-storage also in my reducer.
- Then on my 'Inital State' I always take the local-storage so that if we have anything in the local-storage it means user is logged in

```js
initial_state = {
  userName: localstorage.getItem('user_name')
}
```

That's how you can keep your user logged in and at the time of logout erase the local-storage as well as the reducer.

Comment: Yeah, JWT isnt the problem as such. I was just figuring out how to handle the username, but yeah I think I got my answer, I can use  ```userName: localstorage.getItem('username')``` in the initialstate itself. Also, Side note, I think its not secure to keep the token in redux. Either just localstorage or a cookie would be better I guess.

Comment: Yes you can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can send the user as a prop to the header.  That is kind of the preferred method.  Have the user login and save their app state with redux of the `useState` hook that is now available in React.

To your second question, JWTs preserve session data.  Rerendering the page won't cause that to disappear.  Well-designed apps have JWT with an expiration time (usually 20 minutes or less).

I worked on a voting application that did exactly what you're looking for and did not require any global state management.  Feel free to pick through it. It's an open-source project.  I think we used Auth0 or Google's Oauth library to do authentication.

Here's the code for the React header(navbar): https://github.com/poll-pal/poll-pal/blob/master/src/Components/Header/Header.js

Here's the code for the Express server that backed it: https://github.com/poll-pal/poll-pal/blob/master/server/routes/auth.js

Comment: In your code, inside App component(from where the prop is passed), you are initializing the user in componentDidMount. Now if the user has just logged in, he/she is redirected to the homepage. But now to reflect the username in the navbar, you will need to re render your entire App right?

Comment: It should just render the header component with new props (if the user has already logged in).  The entire app will rerender once, when a login occurs or when other app-level data occurs that changes state, but that will not cause the JWTs from the Oauth session to be lost.

Comment: Short answer @jmvaswani the header in that app is a static component